# WordPress link to external website

Tags: wordpress

I want to link a tab so as to one click goes to subdomain in WordPress.Also want to have woo commerce on one tab along side website tabs and opens on same page

Comment: are you talking about the drop-down in the wordpress backend?
We will need more information to help you. Paste some code, tell us what you have tried and describe your problem more precise.

Comment: This isn't a question, and this isn't a code to order service. Do some research, attempt what you want to do and if/when you need help with it, come back post your question and code and we'll do what we can.

Comment: @Tom m yes I m talking about dropdown tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

prepare your woo Commerce page in WordPress if you download the plugin and publish it, After that go to WordPress appearance and choose menu 
[Wordpress Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kic0D.png)

Comment: Ok let me check

Comment: Ok got it I was taking that as theme

Comment: What about removing default page which has sidebar and appears in woo commerce product page